# String Matching in Java or C#

Tags: java, c#

Task assigning to me is to find the all possible combinations of a given pattern from the String. Like given string is 01001001001001.
I have to find for how many times 01001 appears in the given string? So the correct answer that i required is 4 possible combinations of 01001 are present in the given String. How can i code to make it possible in java or C#? I have tried this but it results only two strings match.

```
    package regularexpressions;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RegularExpressions {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the main string: ");

        String main = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the pattern string: ");

        String patern = sc.nextLine();

       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patern);
       // get a matcher object

       Matcher m = p.matcher(main); 

   System.out.println("The input String is="+input);

       System.out.println("The Pattren to be recgnoized is="+pattren);

       while(m.find()) {

           count++;
           System.out.println("Match number "
                              + count);
           System.out.println("start(): "
                              + m.start());
           System.out.println("end(): "
                              + m.end());                  

}

}
```

Comment: you should at least try to do your homework and come with a code sample when / if it's not working

Comment: Agreed. at least show some evidence of giving this a go

Comment: Search via `IndexOf("01001", start)` until no more variants are found.

Comment: String a = "01001001001001";
    String b = "01001";
    System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(a, b));

Answer (score 0):

**This is you want Copy and paste in java public class and try**

```
String givenString = "01001001001001";

    String pattern = "01001";
    int j = 0,count = 0;
    int matchChar = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (givenString.length() - pattern.length() + 1); i++)
    {

        if(givenString.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j))
        {
            temp = i;
            while(givenString.charAt(temp) == pattern.charAt(j) && j < pattern.length() - 1)
                {
                    matchChar++;
                    temp++;
                    j++;
                }
            j = 0;
        }
        j = 0;
        if(matchChar == 4)
                count += 1;
        matchChar = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```